# git svn fetch: Could not unmemoize function `check_cherry_pick', because it was not memoized to begin with

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm hitting the following error while running `git svn fetch`:

```
Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/YAML/Loader.pm line 517, <$IN> line 1.
YAML Error: Can't parse double quoted string
   Code: YAML_PARSE_ERR_BAD_DOUBLE
   Line: 2
   Document: 1
 at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/YAML/Loader.pm line 523.

Could not unmemoize function `check_cherry_pick', because it was not memoized to begin with at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 1639.
END failed--call queue aborted at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 49.
```

Previously [something similar happened](http://spectlog.com/content/Index_mismatch_error_git-svn) and solution was `git svn reset -r N` which is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Googling led me to [the following solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-version-control/KWD-LUyMYbA/TJIbf4c1on8J):

```
rm -rf .git/svn/.caches
```