# git svn clone ending with error I can't figure out

Tags: git, svn

I'm getting this error while importing a large SVN repo into Git. It runs for a long time and then dies with the error below.

```
D       resources/images/display-manager/
W: -empty_dir: trunk/resources/images/display-manager
Checking svn:mergeinfo changes since r29645: 29 sources, 1 changed
YAML::XS::Load Error: The problem:

    found unexpected end of stream

was found at document: 1, line: 127922, column: 120
while scanning a quoted scalar at line: 127922, column: 3

Could not unmemoize function `check_cherry_pick2', because it was not memoized to begin with at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 1723.
END failed--call queue aborted.
```

I'm just spinning my tires here. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Duplicate - have a look here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074208/git-svn-fetch-could-not-unmemoize-function-check-cherry-pick-because-it-was

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git svn fetch: Could not unmemoize function \`check\_cherry\_pick', because it was not memoized to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074208/git-svn-fetch-could-not-unmemoize-function-check-cherry-pick-because-it-was)